# Reading Data From an External Excel File

Tags: vba, excel

So I run a certain report quite often, and then I have to manually input about 30 fields from it into a VBA userform that does some calculations. They recently updated the site I get this report from so they now offer this specific report in an excel file.

What I want to do is add a browse button to my userform where I can search for the file and then it will automatically populate the data fields. I am pretty handy with VBA (or at least used to be), but I don't know much about this specific issue here. Was hoping someone could give a hand!

Thanks

Comment: Need a little clarification here - do you know where the file is with the data fields?  If so, have your button perform a `Workbooks.Open` to it, then retrieve whatever you need, close it, do your calcs etc?  If you want the user to specify the file, look at the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` command to let them select the file in question? Generally you're more likely to be helped in here if you post your efforts and show that you have tried to solve it yourself first.

Comment: You haven't actually stated a "specific issue here."

Comment: Sorry guys, I wasn't actually looking for someone to do this for me! Just wanted a push in the right direction. I'll take a look at the FileDialog command, that seems like what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
           & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
           & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

You can query directly against excel files. I will add that the file may need to be "clean/tidy'd up" for it to work perfectly. Either way this should help.

*edit* this is asuming you download it first. I would have to play around to automate getting the file form the site first then querying it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to work frequently with other workbooks and I do the following:

```
Dim reportBookPath As String
Dim reportwb As Workbook

reportBookPath = "C:\Users\......\filename.xlsx"
Set reportwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=reportBookPath)
reportwb.Application.Visible = False
```

Then when I want to access anything in that workbook, it is just a matter of doing:

```
valueDesired = reportwb.Worksheets("Desired Sheet").Cells(row,column).Value
```

To use this to open workbooks with dynamic filenames, you would need to have some sort of established pattern for the workbook names. If you had that, you could use regular expressions to open the appropriate workbook. To do this you would:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim shiftRegExp As RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim pathToFile As String
```

The following line:

```
strPattern = "[S|s]hift( ?)1( ?)\.xlsx$"
```

is the real powerful part in all of this code. This particular regular expression will be true for any file name that ends as any of the following:

shift1.xlsx ; shift 1.xlsx ; shift1. xlsx ; shift 1 .xlsx ; Shift1.xlsx ; Shift 1.xlsx ; Shift1 .xlsx ; Shift 1 .xlsx

You can use [this link](https://regex101.com/) to test your own regular expressions.

```
Set shiftRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\....\workbook directory")

With shiftRegExp

.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = strPattern

End With
```

You make use of the regular expression by iterating through all of the files in your chosen directory until you find a file that matches your regular expression. Obviously, if you have multiple files that match your regular expression, you will have issues.

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If shiftRegExp.test(objFile.Path) Then
    pathToFile = objFile.Path
    Exit For
End If

Next objFile
```

Comment: I would still need to dynamically get the file path name, I'm assuming using the Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) command. I am just not familiar with this command. Thoughts?

Comment: @ct4242, I added to my answer above. If your situation allows for it, regular expressions could solve your problem.